# Referencing Table data in View that references a different table [MVC]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 Tables with separate Controllers & Views in the Same Database one called

`Part`

Another Called

`Assembly`

In my Edit View i get the data from the `Parts` Table.
I need to ALSO get specific data from the `Assembly` Table in the Edit view for Parts. The data i need to get has the same `Column name`.

I need to use `@foreach` to get / display this data in the Part Edit View

Below is what i'm using

`@model WebSpares3.Data.Part`

`@foreach (var item in Model.Assembly) {`

How can i specifically reference the Name from The Assembly table into the parts data if they have the same column name in each of the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Model or ViewModel for this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public Part MyPart  { get; set;}
   public Assembly MyAssembly { get; set;}      
}
```

Then this is what you will pass to your view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
   model.MyPart = new MyPart ()
                       {
                          ColumnName1 = "Details here",
                          ColumnName2 = 1
                       }
   model.MyAssembly = //populate your Assembly details class

   return View(model); //return your view with two classes on one class
}
```

Now you can do this  on your razor view:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyPart.ColumnName1)
 @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyPart.ColumnName2)
```

and this one:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyAssembly.ColumnName1)
 @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MyAssembly.ColumnName2)
```

Comment: I've done this however, i'm still getting an error of 'Part does not contain a definition for 'My Assembly'' in the View when i do 

`@foreach (var model in Model.MyAssembly.Name)`

Comment: I would like to clarify, is MyAssembly.Name a class or an enumerable or list? Since no need to iterate it if its just one model and not an ienumerable.

Comment: It's an entry from a column of a database , so it would be a class i believe. I'm new to MVC haha.